# How to work locally with a forked version of npm package dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Let's say my react project has a dependency on LibA which itself depends on LibB.
Now, I want to extend functionality of LibA and LibB.

This is what I tried:

- I forked `LibB`
- I forked `LibA` and updated it's dependency to a local version of `ForkedLibB`

```json
// LibB/package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "LibB": "file:/path/to/ForkedLibB"
  }
}
```

- I update my project dependency to `ForkedLibA`

```json
// Main/package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "LibA": "file:/path/to/ForkedLibA"
  }
}
```

How can I make my workflow faster?
Right now for every change that I make to `ForkedLibB`, it appears that I have to rebuild `ForkedLibB`, switch to `ForkedLibA`, run `yarn update`, rebuild `ForkedLibB`, switch to `Main` and run `yarn update` again.

Is this how it has to be done? I can't afford to wait 2 minutes every time I add a small change.

Comment: You can first use `npm link` to install both LibA and LibB globally on you local machine. Then in LibA, install LibB from local path using `npm i <path to LibB>`. Then in Main, install LibA from from local path using `npm i <path to LibA>`.  You may still need to build LibA and LibB depending on library setup but at least this way you shouldn't need to do `yarn update` every time there is a change.